# Move an Excel Range to an Access table via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to move an arbitrary range to an MSAccess table efficiently, which surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be a lot about doing. The range in question may or may not be continuous, but I can't sensibly save the open workbook before moving the data, so Create name --> Save --> `Select * Into tblTABLE from [Microsoft Excel;Data Source=<Path to file>].[<NamedRange>]` isn't an option directly.

Instead, I'm copying the range into a new workbook, and then performing that opeartion there. This is woefully inefficient, but probably more efficient than saving a new copy of the entire workbook in the temp directory before deleting.

Ideally, I'd like to change the import approach to something with a little less overhead, though. Can anyone think of a better approach than this that can still deal with non-continuous ranges?

Thanks,
Toby

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient manner I found to accomplish this was through looping - turns out opening an Read/Write recordset to the Access table and reading in the values was a lot more efficient than copying and pasting (a little surprisingly), at least for moderate numbers of lines (say, up to ~1000).

Obviously, appropriate EnableEvents/SceenUpdating/Calculation settings applied and restored, else performance is dreadful.

I'm still, however, highly interested in any better solutions anyone might have.